# How to stop div from pushing other divs down?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have some divs.

I am using a Grid system and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to stop divs from pushing others down.

When I try to set the margin top to say 50px for the border div it pushes everything else down.

I do not want to use position absolute due to being responsive grid system.

```css
body {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: Lato;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 640px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 3.2em;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 160px;
}
ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
#circle {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px 20px 5px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.border {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-top:;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <div class="grid">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="c12">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <ul>
        <li id="circle">H</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li id="circle">A</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li id="circle">W</li>
        <li>Work</li>
        <li id="circle">C</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="c12">
      <h2>Exquisite Web Development</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: try `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 2):

On the border div, you can remove the margin and add:

```
position: relative;
top: 50px;
```

Comment: Did not work.
Still pushes everything down...
Again, I have tried everything.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvyzVO

Comment: works okay for me. What browser are you using? Here's my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmVZzO

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
position: relative; 
top: 50px;
```

Here is a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpyMKp

For your border div. This is a way to move an element from it's usual position without affecting the other divs.

Although I feel like you would be better off just reducing the margin-top on your ul element, and you could achieve the same layout without it being a sort of "hacky" solution.

Comment: I need the border element to sit ontop of another hence why I need to move the margin.

Comment: Remove your margin-top on the border element, the property that you want is just      top: 50px;         Same as I have it in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the problematic margin is here:

```
ul {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Remove or shrink that and add your margin to `.border` as intended.

```css
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: Lato;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 640px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 160px;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
#circle {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px 20px 5px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.border {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 50px;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="c12">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <ul>
        <li id="circle">H</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li id="circle">A</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li id="circle">W</li>
        <li>Work</li>
        <li id="circle">C</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="c12">
      <h2>Exquisite Web Development</h2>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. Be sure you know how to use your browse's document inspector. It's an invaluable tool for front-enders.